# How to manually kill a specific (running) thread from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

For the purpose of testing, I need to **manually** kill a named thread (in a debugging session) from Visual Studio - or any other tool that allows me to do that?

But the `Threads` Debug Window in Visual Studio 2010 only has a `Freeze` option in the thread's context menu, and Sysinternal's [ProcessExplorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) only lists processes, not threads.

Is there a way to manually kill a specific (running) thread?

Comment: Have you tried `taskkill`? Ex. `TASKKILL /F /IM untitled.exe` or may be there is a PID for each thread. So, first take a look with `Tasklist`.. not sure, just trying to help

Comment: You can try Thread.Abort in immediate window...but I'm not sure how to get matching Thread object - so posting as comment.

Comment: @BrOSs, taskkill will not let you do anything with threads.

Comment: What does killing a thread do that freezing it doesn't?  If it's frozen it won't ever execute any code again; about the only think I can think of is that memory for the thread and everything in it won't be reclaimed.  Are you running out of memory in your app as a result of this?

Comment: @Servy I just tried your suggestion (to freeze) and while it effectively cancels the thread's operations, attempting to programmitically re-`RunWorkerAsync()` it doesn't result in reviving the thread. What I really want to simulate is terminating it.

Comment: @ateiob BackgroundWokers aren't really designed to be reusable.  Even if it failed more gracefully you shouldn't be relying on re-running it's async code.  Recreate the BGW if you want to start a new background thread.

Comment: @Servy Ouch! I didn't know that I can't rely on re-running a BackgroundWoker's async code. Why is it there then?

Comment: @ateiob The background worker doesn't start when it's first created because you need to 1) create the BGW 2) attach handlers to events to the BGW 3) start the actual task.  If 3 happens before 2 then events that your program assumes will fire might not fire, possibly because the async task is *really* short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to just kill a thread because the designers of the language want to avoid the following problem: your thread takes a lock, and then you kill it before it can release it... now anyone who needs that lock will get stuck.

What you have to do is use some global variable to tell the thread to stop. You have to manually, in your thread code, check that global variable and return if you see it indicates you should stop.

Comment: Note the *"manually"* in my OP: I don't want to do that programmatically. I just need to this from the debugger.

Comment: @ateiob: Note the fact that what you want to do is probably not possible.

Comment: @caesay That's why I am asking. :) If no one comes up with a "can do" answer, I will accept this one.